# Lattice Stick Number vs. Stick Number of Knot

Tags: knot-theory, stick-knots, geometry, discrete-geometry

Can the lattice stick number of a knot be bounded
by the stick number of the knot?

The stick number
$S(K)$ of a knot $K$ is the fewest number of segments
needed to realize it by a simple 3D polygon.
The lattice stick number $S_L(K)$ is the fewest segments in a realization in the cubic
lattice, with all segments parallel to a coordinate axis.
For example, the stick number of the trefoil knot $K=3_1$
is 6, and its lattice stick number is 12
(the latter a result of Huh and Oh from 2005).

My question is whether it is possible to bound $S_L(K)$
by $m S(K)$, where $m$ is some multiplier factor. 
Ideally $m$ would be a constant, but perhaps it is more realistic
to expect it to depend
on the complexity of the knot (e.g., on its crossing number
$cr(K)$).
What I have in mind is replacing each stick in a stick realization
by a bounded lattice path.

**Addendum**.  Tracy Hall's clever example below indicates that it is unlikely that $m$ could be a constant.

Comment: Clarification: for lattice stick number, can a "segment" by arbitrarily long, or are you counting the total number of unit segment lengths?  (Both questions look equally interesting a priori.)

Comment: @Cap Khoury: The former. In general, the length of the sticks is not part of the definition of `$S_L(K)$`. One stick can consist of several collinear unit-length segments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised by something like a quadratic bound, or possibly something reasonable in terms of another complexity measure for the knot, but I see no hope for making $m$ constant.  Consider the following construction: given $m$, choose some large number like $N=(10m)^6$ of points uniformly at random in the unit sphere, and connect them sequentially in a cycle with straight line segments to define a knot $K$.  By construction $K$ has stick number no more than $N$, but each stick has a long narrow tunnel that it must traverse in a very precise direction, which is difficult to do with only $m$ lattice sticks.  Of course any one tunnel can be made shorter and wider with an affine transformation (or any small collection of tunnels, with a piecewise affine transformation) but I am convinced (without attempting a rigorous proof) that with probability approaching $1$ a knot so constructed has a lattice stick number much higher than $mS_L(K)$.

Comment: This is a convincing example, Tracy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The lattice stick number is obviously bounded by some function of the stick number: there are finitely many graphs with stick number at most k (because there are finitely many line segment arrangements in the plane and choices of over-under relationships on each crossing) so the lattice stick number of stick-number-k graphs is just the max of the lattice stick number of this finite set of graphs. This argument doesn't give an explicit or good bound on the number, though.